# Embedding HTML5 Canvas in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, shopify, createjs, easeljs

I am working on a project where I have done an animation in Adobe Flash CC and exported it in HTML5 canvas by easel js.

**My Process in Shopify is:**

---

I have included all the scripts in the header
`easeljs-0.8.1.min.js, tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js, movieclip-0.8.1.min.js, preloadjs-0.6.1.min.js, bg_animation.js` and I have instantiated the init function in the body tag.

**My Script is:**

---

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};
    ss = ss||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadFile({src:"bg_animation_atlas_.json", type:"spritesheet", id:"bg_animation_atlas_"}, true);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
    var queue = evt.target;
    ss["bg_animation_atlas_"] = queue.getResult("bg_animation_atlas_");
    exportRoot = new lib.bganimation();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
```

The json file named bg_animation_atlas_.json and the bg image named bg_animation_atlas_.png are on the asset url.

My script in json file is

```
{"images": ["bg_animation_atlas_.png"], "frames": [[0,1423,4002,1421],[0,0,4002,1421]]}
```

But what I find the canvas animation is not showing not only that there is an error in console:
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://online-store-63.myshopify.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://online-store-63.myshopify.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
and 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNumFrames' of undefined

What I think it may be path problem where easel js can't take it's action, but I can not figure out the reason.